# Magento Catalog price rules not applying to product

Tags: magento-1.9

We have created server Catalog Price Rules in our Magento 1 website, all rules working properly after clicking on "Apply Rules" button but next day all rules stop working automatically and not work until click on "Apply Rules" button again.

Every day we have to click on "Apply Rules" button to work all RUles. If not clicking every day then price resets to original price and Catalog price rules stop working.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.